# different ways to iterate a list of tuples

Tags: python

I do not get to see the difference between this:

```
def guest_list(guests):
   for (name, age,job) in guests:
       print("Guest {} is {} years old and works as {}".format(name, age, job))
```

and this:

```
def guest_list(guests):
    for x in guests:
        name, age, profession = x
        print("{} is {} years old and works as {}".format(name, age, profession))
```

Could someone explain the difference? if there is some

Comment: Both perform tuple unpacking. Do you see any difference in output?

Comment: output is the same that is why I do not get the difference if there is any. The thing is that I am doing a online crash course and the first example did not pass the test as the second one did. That is what confused me

Comment: these two are identical, may be the `print` statement formatting made the difference between passing and failing of the code?

Comment: The first one will print "Guest" in addtion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference as far as I know.
When you write `(name, age,job)`, python unpack the object and let you have the variable right away.